VerifyTests XML CData and Comments removed
Using VerifyTests on a c# project and MSTest, I am calling VerifyXml on
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><person><![CDATA[name is John Doe]]></person>

and
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><person><!-- name is John Doe --></person>

In the 1st case the verified xml appears without the CDATA
<person>name is John Doe</person>

In the 2nd case the comment is removed from the document
<person></person>

I tried looking in VerifySettings but could not find any setting that could control these to be saved during verification. Any ideas?

this is fixed in V28.3.2
https://github.com/VerifyTests/Verify/pull/1352
And here is some extra text since stackoverflow is a PITA
